# SQL ExecuteNonQuery throws "Incorrect syntax near '0'."

Tags: c#, sql, executenonquery, sqlparameter

I have the following code that I am using to insert a number of rows into a database:

```
   _conn.Open();
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(_insert[0].ToString(), _conn);
   command.Parameters.AddRange((_insert[1] as List<SqlParameter>).ToArray());
   Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   _conn.Close();
```

The command (_insert[1].ToString()) is:

```
"INSERT INTO Candidate (id, name) VALUES ({0},{1}),({2},{3}),({4},{5}),({6},{7}),
({8},{9}),({10},{11}),({12},{13}),({14},{15}),({16},{17}),({18},{19}),({20},{21}),
({22},{23}),({24},{25}),({26},{27}),({28},{29}),({30},{31}),({32},{33}),({34},{35}),
({36},{37}),({38},{39})"
```

and the command parameters are like this (from VS debug):

```
[0] - ParameterName = "0", SqlDbType = BigInt, Value = 21400
[1] - ParameterName = "1", SqlDbType = NVarChar, Value = "Dan Smith"
[2] - ParameterName = "2", SqlDbType = BigInt, Value = 21401
[3] - ParameterName = "3", SqlDbType = NVarChar, Value = "Doug Smith"
[4] - ParameterName = "4", SqlDbType = BigInt, Value = 21402
[5] - ParameterName = "5", SqlDbType = NVarChar, Value = "Danielle Smith"
```

The error I am getting is "Incorrect syntax near '0'."  Can someone tell me what is causing this?

In case it matters here is where I am creating the parameter array (separate function that iterates over JSON returned from API):

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> _attribute in _field)
    {
        // '_score' is an attribute included with each entity when doing a search
        // indicating the matching score of the query, we don't want this in the database
        if (_attribute.Key.ToString() != "_score")
        {
            _insertQuery.AppendFormat("{{{0}}},", _paramNumber);
            _paramValues.Add(new SqlParameter(_paramNumber.ToString(), _attribute.Value));
            _paramNumber++;
        }
    }
    return new object[] {_insertQuery.ToString(), _paramValues };
```

I am doing this as I am retrieving various objects from an API and then inserting into a local database.  I cannot create a class for each of these objects (requirements are to make this generic).

**UPDATE**:

I updated the code to prepend the _paramNumber with "@" so each parameter is now @0, @1, etc. and I am now getting this error:

```
"Incorrect syntax near '@0'."
```

The insert statement is as follows:

```
"INSERT INTO Candidate (id, name) VALUES ({@0},{@1}),({@2},{@3}),({@4},{@5}),({@6},{@7}),
({@8},{@9}),({@10},{@11}),({@12},{@13}),({@14},{@15}),({@16},{@17}),({@18},{@19}),
({@20},{@21}),({@22},{@23}),({@24},{@25}),({@26},{@27}),({@28},{@29}),({@30},{@31}),
({@32},{@33}),({@34},{@35}),({@36},{@37}),({@38},{@39})"
```

and the parameters are like this:

```
[0] - ParameterName = "@0", SqlDbType = BigInt, Value = 21400
[1] - ParameterName = "@1", SqlDbType = NVarChar, Value = "Dan Smith"
[2] - ParameterName = "@2", SqlDbType = BigInt, Value = 21401
[3] - ParameterName = "@3", SqlDbType = NVarChar, Value = "Doug Smith"
[4] - ParameterName = "@4", SqlDbType = BigInt, Value = 21402
[5] - ParameterName = "@5", SqlDbType = NVarChar, Value = "Danielle Smith"
```

Comment: Well you appear to have parameters in the form `{0}` rather than `@0`. I don't think I've ever seen *SQL* parameters in that form before...

Comment: I updated my code (see edit) but am still getting a similar error.  Is there a way to capture the info passed to SQL via the ExecuteNonQuery command so that I can debug it in SQL?

Comment: You've still got braces around your parameters - why? `{@0}` is not the same as `@0`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.  I have never used the SqlParameter object before and the {{{0}}} was from the example I was trying to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using direct parameters in your query and not formatting the query string itself with String.Format, you should only use parameters with the format @parameterName in your query, like so.

```
"INSERT INTO Candidate (id, name) VALUES (@0,@1),(@2,@3),(@4,@5),(@6,@7),
(@8,@9),(@10,@11),(@12,@13),(@14,@15),(@16,@17),(@18,@19),
(@20,@21),(@22,@23),(@24,@25),(@26,@27),(@28,@29),(@30,@31),
(@32,@33),(@34,@35),(@36,@37),(@38,@39)"
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I infer from your question, you are trying to use `{number}` as parameter names. Which I personally don't think is valid.

You should use `@yourParameterName`